# Problems using lambda expression

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I have a problem with sorting the letters of a word, by the number of occurrences of the letters and if the letters appear the same number of times, it will be sorted at least lexicographically.
I have a code but I get compilation error on the site and 0 points because they use java 7 and I don't know how to solve the last part of the problem without "lambda".

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;

public class prog {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String testString = " ";
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        testString = rd.readLine();
        Map < Character, List < Character >> map = new HashMap < > ();
        for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
            char someChar = testString.charAt(i);
            if (someChar == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            char ch = testString.charAt(i);
            List < Character > characters =
                map.getOrDefault(Character.toLowerCase(ch), new ArrayList < > ());
            characters.add(ch);
            map.put(Character.toLowerCase(ch), characters);
        }
        List < Map.Entry < Character, List < Character >>> list =
            new ArrayList < > (map.entrySet());

        list.sort((o1, o2) - > {
            if (o1.getValue().size() == o2.getValue().size()) {
                return o1.getKey() - o2.getKey();
            }
            return o2.getValue().size() - o1.getValue().size();
        });
        list.forEach(entry - > entry.getValue().forEach(System.out::print));
    }
}
```

Comment: What site? Can't you just choose which java version you want to use?

Comment: Anyway, you will have to implement your own `Comparator`, use `Collections.sort()` and rewrite `forEach` as a simple loop. And change the part with `map.getOrDefault` as well.

Comment: Java 8 is old hat by now. You should report it to the site.   They are doing their patrons a disservice by not supporting it and future, stable, releases.

Comment: @STRKLok You may want to rethink returning subtracted values in your `comparator` implementation.  It doesn't always work and can lead to pitfalls.  It is best to return explicit values of 1, -1, or 0 as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`:

```java
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>> o1, Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>> o2) {
        if (o1.getValue().size() == o2.getValue().size()) {
            return o1.getKey() - o2.getKey();
        }
        return o2.getValue().size() - o1.getValue().size();
    }
});

for (Map.Entry<Character, List<Character>> characterListEntry : list) {
    System.out.println(characterListEntry);
}
```

`Map#getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)` was also introduced in Java 8. you need to change it to something like:

```java
char cKey = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
List<Character> characters = map.containsKey(cKey) ? map.get(cKey) : new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: @OleV.V. no problem, actually I like to do it your way and concatenate comparators where possible.

Comment: As I said in the comment to the question, `map.getOrDefault` need to be changed as well. I think it might be worth mentioning it in your answer as well.

Comment: @WJS the question is about Java 8 and 7 compatibility.

Comment: @M.S. And this site is about helping.  Sometimes, help goes beyond the question at hand. But I reposted the suggestion to the OP since it was their code.

Answer (score 0):

To build the `map` with Java 7 you can do it as follows.

```
        // convert to lower case from the start
        testString = rd.readLine().toLowerCase();

        Map<Character, List<Character>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < testString.length(); i++) {
            char someChar = testString.charAt(i);
            if (someChar == ' ') {
                continue;
            }
            // try and get the list
            List<Character> characters = map.get(someChar);
            if (characters == null) {
                // otherwise, create it
                characters = new ArrayList<>();
                // and put it in the map
                map.put(someChar, characters);
            }
            // add characters to the obtained list.
            characters.add(someChar);
        }
```

For the `Comparator` and other similar implementations, I prefer to use `local classes.  Imo they are cleaner than anonymous classes but do require additional syntax.  If you aren't familiar with these, this would go inside your main class.

```java
    static class CountThenLex implements
                Comparator<Entry<Character, List <Character>>> {
        public int compare(
            Entry<Character, List<Character>> a,
            Entry<Character, List <Character>> b) {
            int asize = a.getValue().size();
            int bsize = b.getValue().size();
            // note that b is sorted first for descending count order.

            int aTob = bsize > asize ? 1 :
                bsize < asize ? -1 : 0;
            if (aTob != 0) {
                return aTob;
            }

            // if the counts are equal, then sort lexically.  Since the Character
            // class implements `Comparable` you can use the natural ordering.
            return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Then you just call sort with an instance of the class.

```java
    Collections.sort(list, new CountThenLex());
```

You will also have to modify your print method as well as other methods since other Java 8 features are also present.  Here is the basic print solution.

```
    for(Entry<?,List<Character>> e : list) {
        for (char c : e.getValue()) {
            System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
```